# 500 Internal Server Error on .py execution

Tags: python, apache

I am trying to have a python script execute on the click of an image but whenever the python script gets called it always throws a 500 Internal Server Error? Here is the text from the log

```
[Sun Feb 15 20:31:04 2015] [error] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/forward.py' failed
[Sun Feb 15 20:31:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.15.51] Premature end of script headers: forward.py, referer: http://192.168.15.76/Testing.html
```

I don't understand why it is saying `Premature end of script header`? I can execute a basic python script that just prints an html header or text. The file I am trying to execute just has some basic wiringPi code that executes fine from the sudo python forward.py command?

EDIT

This is the script I'm trying to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

import wiringpi2 as wiringpi

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupPhys()

wiringpi.pinMode(40, 1)

wiringpi.digitalWrite(40, 1)

time.sleep(2)

wiringpi.digitalWrite(40, 0)

wiringpi.pinMode(40, 0)
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the script?

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. Make sure the script is executable (`chmod +x forward.py`) and that it has a she-bang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python`).
2. Make sure the script's owner & group match up with what user apache is running as.
3. Try running the script from the command line as the apache user. I see that you're testing it with `sudo`. Does it really need `sudo`? If so whatever user is running as apache will also need sudoers access.
4. Since it looks like you're using CGI, try adding: `import cgitb; cgitb.enable();` to the top of your script. This will catch any exceptions and return it as a response instead of causing the script to die.

Comment: I confirmed that the file was indeed executable and I do have the #!/usr/bin/env python line of code at the beginning of my script. I changed the owner and file group to match the user and group that apache is running as and I also confirmed that the user can run the file from a command line. After all of this the server still returns the 500 Internal server error

Comment: Ok, I added another step. Check it out. If you can get other python scripts to work, but you still can't get the exact error from this script, try to cut down the program to just the statement that causes it to die. E.g. the import statement, or one of those wiringpi functions, etc.

Comment: I'm gonna try to comment out specific sections until I can get it to actually compile somewhat. I tried your cgit import suggestion, but to no avail. I will comment back after I try some commenting out.

Comment: Update: I created a new program that turns the wheels by this command os.system("echo 1=185 > /dev/servoblaster") the program executes beautifully but as soon as it is done turning the wheels it says internal server error, but if I have it return some text to the screen it doesn't return internal server error??

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, CGI scripts have to return the text of an HTTP response.

Comment: Whenever I execute the python script it opens a new window, is there any way to get it to run in the background and not change the website at all?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @lost-theory's recommendations, I would also check to make sure:

- You have executable permission on the script.
- Apache has permission to access the folder/file of the script. For example:

  ```
  <Directory /path/to/your/dir>
    <Files *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
  ```

Comment: I have that added to the 000-default file and I have also setup an .httdaccess file to assure the webserver can execute .py files. Also I have ran other python scripts from the webpage in the same directory as the current file, which is what puzzles me?